# Tail recursion in a receive block

Tags: elixir, tail-recursion

I see functions that enclose a receive block getting called recursively seemingly not in the tail position all over the place in elixir example code. For example:

```rb
defmodule A do
  def loop do
    receive do
      :ping ->
         IO.puts "Received :ping"
         loop # <- Tail position?
      :pong ->
         IO.puts "Received :pong"
         loop # <- Also Tail position?
      after
        5000 ->
          loop # <- Also Tail position?
     end
     loop # <- Also Tail position?
  end
end
```

Is receive a special construct that optimizes for tail positions at the end of all match blocks? If so does it apply if the receive block has an `after` block? What if there is code after the receive block in the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, only the very last call to `loop` is tail recursive. Instead of making the recursive call inside the `receive` block, just let the `receive` return and just use the tail-recursive call to loop at the end of the function that is already there.

```
defmodule A do
  def loop do
    receive do
      :ping ->
         IO.puts "Received :ping"
      :pong ->
         IO.puts "Received :pong"
      after
        5000 ->
          nil
     end
     loop
  end
end
```

As a general rule, process loops should always have exactly one recursive call at the end of the `loop` function. That's the simplest way to guarantee that the process will be able to loop infinitely.

However, you *can* loop inside the `receive` block if it is the last statement in the `loop` function. The result will also be tail-recursive. This allows you to conditionally stop the loop based on a received message

```
defmodule A do
  def loop do
    receive do
      :ping ->
         IO.puts "Received :ping"
         loop
      :pong ->
         IO.puts "Received :pong"
         loop
      :stop ->
         IO.puts "Bye Bye"
     end
  end
end
```

Also see http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html#id69762

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Those erlang docs were exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm assuming that the same is true for `case`, etc? That a function called recursively from a condition in `case` is TCO provided nothing is called after the block?

Comment: Yes, this should apply in those situations too.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I should have tested before asking. Wrote three simple recursive functions: one not optimized,  one optimized, and one as recursive call as last statement in `case`... Benchmarked them, **only** the first one tries to blow up memory on large inputs, `case` made no noticeable performance difference